# Expo Router | "Page could not be found"

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, expo-router

I have a file structure as per the below;

[image: file-structure]

I am currently on the [venue] screen and want to navigate to `offer/[offer]`.

I have tried;

```
router.push({
  pathname: "/offer/",
  params: {
    id: id,
  },
});

router.push({
  pathname: `/offer/${id}`,
  params: {
    id: id,
  },
});
```

and I am getting the above error.

### OFFER/_LAYOUT

```
  return (
    <Stack.Screen
      name="[offer]"
      options={{
        headerTitle: "",
        presentation: "modal",
        headerRight: () => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => router.back()}>
            <Icon name="close-line" size={24} color={textColor} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
      }}
    />
  );
```

### VENUE/_LAYOUT

```
return (
    <Stack
      screenOptions={{
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
        },
        headerTintColor: textColor,
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen
        name="[venue]"
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          headerTransparent: true,
          headerTitle: "",
          headerLeft: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => router.back()}>
              <Icon name="arrow-left-line" size={24} color={textColor} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Stack>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong formatting for the route parameter. You need square brackets instead of template strings.

Try using:

```
router.push({
  pathname: "/offer/[id]",
  params: { id: id },
});
```

The file you have called `[offer].tsx` is also potentially the issue. If you are trying to look something up by a slug called `offer`, then you'll need to change the router.push to:

```
router.push({
  pathname: "/offer/[offer]",
  params: { offer: offer.name },
});
```

... or whatever attribute you are accessing when navigating to that route.